# Replacing NA's iteratively using data table in 'R'

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to replace NA's with a random sample from an appropriate group. For example in line 2 the NA is from 'France' with age and time '20-30' '30-40'. Hence I want to take a random sample of the Response column for all other 'France', '20-30', '30-40' observations.

I have the code below which works great but every value is replaced with the same random sample. For example, if I had more than one 'France', '20-30', '30-40' NA, both their corresponding R2's would be the same.

I would like each NA to be sampled independently, but data.table seems to do it 'all at once' hence I can't do that. Any ideas ?

```
DT <- data.table(mydf, key = "Country,Age,Time")
DT[, R2 := ifelse(is.na(Response), sample(na.omit(Response), 1), 
                  Response), by = key(DT)]
DT
#    Index Country   Age  Time Response R2
# 1:     5  France 20-30 30-40        1  1
# 2:     6  France 20-30 30-40       NA  2
# 3:     7  France 20-30 30-40        2  2
# 4:     1 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 5:     2 Germany 20-30 15-20       NA  1
# 6:     3 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 7:     4 Germany 20-30 15-20        0  0
```

where mydf is

```
mydf <- structure(list(Index = 1:7, Country = c("Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", "France"), Age = c("20-30", 
"20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30"), Time = c("15-20", 
"15-20", "15-20", "15-20", "30-40", "30-40", "30-40"), Response = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 2L)), .Names = c("Index", "Country", "Age", 
"Time", "Response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
DT[, is_na := is.na(Response)]
nas <- DT[, sample(Response[!is_na], sum(is_na), TRUE) ,
             by=list(Country, Age, Time)]$V1
DT[, R2 := Response][(is_na), R2 := nas]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(1234)
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf, key = "Country,Age,Time")
```

**First Step**

```
DT[, R2 := sample(na.omit(Response), length(Response), replace = T), 
   by = key(DT)]

DT

#    Index Country   Age  Time Response R2
# 1:     5  France 20-30 30-40        1  1
# 2:     6  France 20-30 30-40       NA  2
# 3:     7  France 20-30 30-40        2  2
# 4:     1 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 5:     2 Germany 20-30 15-20       NA  0
# 6:     3 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 7:     4 Germany 20-30 15-20        0  1
```

**EDIT**

**Second step**

In the first step, you sample accross groups (by = ...) and get a value for R2.
The second step, updates R2 with the Response values that don't have NAs.

```
DT[!is.na(Response), R2 := Response]

DT

#    Index Country   Age  Time Response R2
# 1:     5  France 20-30 30-40        1  1
# 2:     6  France 20-30 30-40       NA  2
# 3:     7  France 20-30 30-40        2  2
# 4:     1 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 5:     2 Germany 20-30 15-20       NA  0
# 6:     3 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 7:     4 Germany 20-30 15-20        0  0
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the random sampling should only replace NA entries... Ex: the last value of R2 should still be 0, just the NA could be 0/1.

Comment: This can't really be correct because, as Arun pointed out the last value in row 7 has changed.

Comment: Well it's a sample accross groups, perhaps you can do this and then update the non NA values from Response in R2. I've edited the answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3154267 I'd take Aruns answer if i were you. I believe his answer is better.